# Clique numbers and Theorem 4.5.1 in "The Probabilistic Method" by Alon and Spencer

Tags: random-graphs, probabilistic-method

> My question is "What is the precise formulation of the following theorem from Alon and Spencer's book *The Probabilistic Method*?"

For context,

1. Let $G(n,1/2)$ be the probability space of *random graphs* where edges are chosen uniformly and independently with probability $1/2$.
2. The quantity $f(k)$ is the expected number of cliques of size $k$ amongst elements of $G(n,1/2)$, i.e. $f(k) = {n \choose k}2^{-{k\choose 2}}$.
3. The authors note that if $k \sim 2\log_2n$, then the function $f(k)$ "drops under one," whatever that means, and $f(k)$ is "very roughly like $n^k2^{-k^2/2}$," whatever that means.
4. If $G$ is a graph, let $\omega(G)$ be the size of the largest clique in $G$, (i.e. the size of the vertex set corresponding to the largest complete subgraph of $G$).

Here's the theorem:

> **Theorem 4.5.1** Let $k = k(n)$ satisfy $k \sim 2\log_2n$ and $f(k) \to \infty$. Then almost always $\omega(G) \ge k$.

What I (think I) understand already:

1. $k\sim 2\log_2n$ means $k(n)/2\log_2n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$.
2. "almost always $\omega(G)\ge k$" means that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N = N(\epsilon)$ such that if $n\ge N$ then for any $G(n,1/2)$, the probability of the event $\{\text{$G\in G(n,1/2)$ satisfies $\omega(G)\ge k$}\}$ is greater than $1-\epsilon$.

What I do not understand:

1. How can we assume that $f(k)\to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$ if we assume that $k\sim 2\log_2n$? By point 3 above in the context I gave, assuming that $k\sim 2\log_2n$ means "$f(k)$ drops under one," so how can $f(k)$ also go to infinity? (Based on this point, an appropriate answer to my question will have to address what is being said precisely in point 3 from the context.)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more precise statement of the theorem would be

> Let $k(n)$ be a function of $n$ such that $k(n) \sim 2 \log_2 n$ as $n \to \infty$ (that is, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{k(n)}{2 \log_2 n} = 1 )$ and $f(k(n)) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\Pr[\omega(G) \ge k(n)]\right) = 1$$ where $G$ has the $G(n,\tfrac12)$ distribution.

So you seem to understand the theorem correctly.

To clarify the statement that seems to be confusing you: saying

> The function $f(k)$ drops under one at $k \sim 2 \log_2 n$

means that if we let $k^*(n)$ be the least value $k$ (for a fixed value of $n$) such that $f(k) < 1$, then $k^*(n) \sim 2 \log_2 n$.

There are lots of functions $k(n)$ satisfying $k(n) \sim 2 \log_2 n$. Some of them will satisfy $f(k(n)) < 1$ for all $n$, and some others will have $f(k(n)) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. In fact, for $k$ in this range, $f(k)$ changes so rapidly that we can define a function $k(n)$ with $f(k(n)+1) \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$ and yet $f(k(n)-1) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. The theorem requires that we pick a "going-to-$\infty$" kind of $k$.

Also, the statement

> $f(k)$ is very roughly like $n^k 2^{-k^2/2}$

is, just as it says, a very rough asymptotic estimate: it's not accurate to within a $1+o(1)$ factor or even to within a constant factor, but it's close to the truth. More precisely, going from $\binom nk$ to $n^k$ and from $2^{-\binom k2}$ to $2^{-k^2/2}$ both drop a factor which is an exponential function of $k$: much less significant than either of the factors we keep.

We could make the statement precise by saying something like $\log f(k) \sim \log (n^k 2^{-k^2})$ if $k \sim 2 \log_2 n$ (both as $n \to \infty$), but that's missing the point: the reason we make this estimate is to get a rough idea of how big $f(k)$ is before we analyze it more precisely.

Comment: Thanks very much, I think this clears it up. Could you explain the notation $\text{Pr}_{G\sim G(n,1/2)}[...]$? Also, could you give an example of some function $k$ that has the property $f(k)\to \infty$?

Comment: I use $Pr_{X \sim D}[\dots]$ to denote a probability with respect to a random variable $X$ following distribution $D$. As for an example of a function $k$ with this property, Mathematica's `Limit` command tells me that $k = 2\log_2 n - \sqrt{\log_2 n}$ works.

Comment: I am not very familiar with distributions. Is my interpretation of the "almost always" bit equivalent to what you are saying about distributions? Thanks again. I'm not really sure what $G$ is when you say "where $G$ has the $G(n,1/2)$ distribution".

Comment: Your "almost always" is equivalent to my "almost always" - I just wanted to be consistent and use the language of limits everywhere it applies. $G(n,1/2)$ is a probability distribution in my view since it assigns a probability to each value of $G$.